# Recurrence Substitution Method of $T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+n$

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, substitution

I need to prove $$T\Big(\frac{n}{2}\Big)+T\Big(\frac{n}{3}\Big)+n \leq cn,$$ by induction where
$$T(n) \leq \frac{cn}{2} +\frac{cn}{3}+n=n\Big(\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c}{3}+1\Big).$$
Everything in the parenthesis is a constant, but I can't just ignore the constant in an induction proof. The book says: "Mathematical induction does not work unless we prove the exact form of the inductive hypothesis" (CLRS introduction to Algorithm, 3rd edition, page 85), so I can't say that $(c/2+c/3+1)$ is just a constant. What am I missing? I've tried to figure out the answer by looking at the subtracting constant technique on the same page of CLRS ([CLRS substitution method "subtracting constant" technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867203/clrs-substitution-method-subtracting-constant-technique)), but as far as I can see it only works with added constants and not multiplication.

Comment: Choose $c$ such that $\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c}{3}+1\leq c$. Solving

$$\frac{5c}6 + 1 \leq c \implies 6\leq c$$

Comment: Also what's the base case of the recursion? $T(1) = k$ for some $k$?

Comment: What integers $n$ is $T(n)$ defined for? Integers in the form $2^a3^b$?

Comment: Or does $T(\frac n2)$ actually mean $T(\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor)$?

Comment: We haven't been given a base case for the recursion. My guess is that the base case is suspected to be T(1) = 1. We were tasked to make a recursion tree to find the best guess to use in the substitution method. I think your chosen value for c is exactly what they expect. (Sorry for the slow respond. Didn't know I had to press show comments to get to your)